# Slow Script porting from c++ to c# unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to use the following algorithm in a unity script (its an application to visualize graphs in 3d space):

https://github.com/godlikemouse/ForceDirectedLayout/blob/master/src/layout.cc

Now when i run the above mentioned code in c++ it takes around 5-10 seconds to complete its iterations. I've ported the entire code to a unity c# script and it takes around 20 minutes to completely run. I really dont know why this is happening and dont understand where to start looking. If anyone can guide me in the right direction, it would be really appreciated.

Comment: maybe if you post your c# code we can help ^^

Answer (score 0):

I would anticipate some slowdown, but a couple of seconds at the most. If it is taking 20 minutes then there is an issue with your port.

A couple of likely candidates:

1. You're outputting a lot of information to the console, this can slow things down dramatically so don't do it unless needed
2. You're unnecessarily creating objects and / or garbage which needs to be collected.

Perhaps the best thing to do is use the Unity Profiler whilst the code is being executed. It'll give you some idea of where the time is being spent. You can enhance the information by inserting your own samples: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Profiler.BeginSample.html

Answer (score 0):

I found that my C# code runs slow in Unity as well. I think this is due to the runtime environment/version and possible compiler optimizations not being made. Maybe lots of overhead as well.

Be sure to test the performance after building and running the compiled Unity project.  In my tests, running Unity C# scripts after launching from the Editor will run at about 13% the speed compared to building and running the executable.

But even then, further tests show that my C# running in the compiled project only runs at 50% the speed of the same code running in a console application.

See this answer: 
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/146100/121804

I didn't look too deep into what your linked algorithm is doing, but to help speed things up: if possible, turn those divisions into multiplication, find a way to not use sqrt, findNode(id) function could be greatly sped up by storing nodes in a hashmap (dictionary).